# Wait for parent python dataclass to be initiated before initialize child class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-dataclasses

I have a `Parent` and `Child` class in python. They work when defined the usual way, but if I use the `dataclass` module then I have a problem because `Child` class wants to access field that are not defined in `Parent` class yet.

Example code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Parent_Dataclass:
    a: str = field(init=False)
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.a = 'A is initialiazed here.'

@dataclass
class Child_DataClass(Parent_Dataclass):
    def __post_init__(self):
        print(self.a)

class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'A is initialiazed here.'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(self.a)

c = Child() # Works !
c_dc = Child_DataClass() # Error !
```

Output:

```
A is initialiazed here.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xxx\test_dataclass_inheritance.py", line 25, in <module>
    c_dc = Child_DataClass()
  File "<string>", line 3, in __init__
  File "c:\xxx\test_dataclass_inheritance.py", line 17, in __post_init__
    print(self.a)
AttributeError: 'Child_DataClass' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: Nowhere do you initialize a `.a` attribute in the parent class. Where do you think you are doing that? `a = 'A is initialiazed here.'` creates a local variable. This is really strange, since you seem to already know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Also, in your child class post-init, you don't call the parent class post-init, again, this is quite strange since you do it correctly in the other version. Not sure where your confusion is stemming from

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 99% sure that is his bug ... you should use `self.a = XXX` instead in your `Parent_Dataclass`

Comment: you should familiarize yourself with `super()` usage.

Comment: @JoranBeasley also calling the parent class method would be required I'm pretty sure

Comment: @AhmedAEK they seem to be familiar with it!

Comment: Lot of answers very quick. What I'm trying to do is to initialize in `self.a` in parent class with `dataclass` decorator in both parent and child class. Calling super().__init__() in `Child_DataClass` `__post_init__` gives a `maximum recursion depth` error.

Comment: @OliverMohrBonometti you should call the `super().method()` where method is the name of the function you are in, so if you are in a function named `__init__` you will call `super().__init__()` but when you are in a function named `__post_init__` which function do you think you should call ?

Comment: Ok, now I see... I had `a =` insted of `self.a =` also, thanks for the `super().__post_init__()`, that was the answer. I'm editting the `self.a` thing